# Not able to push my code into AWS EB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been facing issue with pushing my **ruby on rails** code into **AWS ElasticBeansTalk** server. I first time was able to initialize the EB, commit and push the code and tried to run the EB server. Everything was fine, but after a few commits, suddenly it is raising the exception as following.

```
remote: error: Unable to create application version: You cannot have more than 500 Application Versions. Either remove some Application Versions or request a limit increase.
```

I am not able to find what to do with that. 
Can anybody help me out to achieve the solution clearly please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13):

The error code suggests you've pushed a very large number of builds onto the Elastic Beanstalk environment. Try going in to your AWS Console, and go to `Elastic Beanstalk`, and from the `Actions` button for your application, select `View Application Versions`.

Most probably, you'll find 500 different versions of your application here. Select as many old ones as you wish, and do `Delete` to remove these. Then you should be able to continue.

(Of course, if my hunch is correct, a more interesting question is *how on earth* you've managed to upload 500 different versions of your application. I'm not running Ruby on Rails, so I'm not too familiar with that environment...)

Good luck!

Comment: It's pretty easy if you continuously deploy to production and use `git aws.push` to do it. :)

Comment: Note there is a new command to help automate this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30060544/827254

Answer (score 1):

Use `eb labs cleanup-versions --num-to-leave=some_value` to leave "some_value" number of last application versions and `eb labs cleanup-versions --help` to get a full list of available commands. Notice, that **eb labs** is experimental branch and its syntax may differ based on **eb cli** version.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the older application versions, git aws.push started to work again. It would be nice if the version limit error was returned by git aws.push as it would have saved a lot of time.

So follow below steps to resolve this isue.

1. logged in to console
2. Go to Elastic Beanstalk and select you application and environment
3. Find button "Upload and deploy" below text 'running version' and click it
4. To deploy a previous version, go to the "Application Versions page".
5. Select your last commit and delete this version label.
   6  Again try to deploy with the new version.