# cannot deploy - ERROR: You cannot have more than 500 Application Versions

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I get the following error when deploying to EB:

> ERROR: You cannot have more than 500 Application Versions. Either
>   remove some Application Versions or request a limit increase.

I went manually and deleted some versions.
I don't want deploys to fail because of this limit. 
Is there a way in Elastic Beanstalk to auto-evict unused versions?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

A feature was recently added to eb cli (v3.3) to cleanup old versions

https://m.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/340ce0/whats_the_thinking_behind_beanstalks_versioning/

Copying command from reddit link

```
$ eb labs cleanup-versions --help
usage: eb labs cleanup-versions [options...]

Cleans up old application versions.

optional arguments:
--num-to-leave NUM    number of versions to leave DEFAULT=10
--older-than DAYS     delete only versions older than x days DEFAULT=60
--force               don't prompt for confirmation
```

Comment: super! that's the reason posting your own answer is great. it's the best way to validate it.

Comment: Good for bulk deletion of old versions, but you'll run into the same problem again in the future. Better to set a lifecycle policy as per my answer below.

Comment: Absolutely, I agree that feature is the preferred way to manage application versions now

Answer (score 31):

### You can manage lifecycle policies from the AWS console now.

1. In the **Actions** drop-down on the right hand side of the application you'd like to manage, click **View application versions**.
2. Click on the **Settings** button on the top right and you'll be able to configure the amount of versions you'd like to keep around:
   [image: Lifecycle policies]
3. If you have already reached the limit, you must manually first delete some versions to allow this lifecycle policy to kick in (for an explanation read the note below).

### Note

From the [Configuring Application Version Lifecycle Settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-lifecycle.html) documentation:

> Elastic Beanstalk applies an application's lifecycle policy each time
>   you create a new application version, and deletes up to 100 versions
>   each time the lifecycle policy is applied. Elastic Beanstalk deletes
>   old versions after creating the new version, and does not count the
>   new version towards the maximum number of versions defined in the
>   policy.
>
> Elastic Beanstalk does not delete application versions that are
>   currently being used by an environment, or application versions
>   deployed to environments that were terminated less than ten weeks
>   before the policy was triggered.
>
> The application version limit applies across all applications in a
>   region. If you have several applications, configure each application
>   with a lifecycle policy appropriate to avoid reaching the limit.
>   Elastic Beanstalk only applies the policy if the application version
>   creation succeeds, so if you have already reached the limit, you must
>   delete some versions manually prior to creating a new version.

Comment: Thanks, that's the real long-term solution to the problem. IMO AWS should enable it by default.

Comment: Edit - Answered my own question, updating this answer to provide the additional info!I set this up, but it doesn't seem to have retroactively kicked in, I'm still getting the too many versions error. I can of course just manually delete some versions for now, but I'm concerned that eventually I'll see the same issue. Is there any documentation on when these changes take effect / what it does when you had too many versions prior to setting it?

Comment: I'm having the same issue you are @JakeT. with this not kicking in retroactively - did you end up seeing the same issue after deleting versions existing before the policy?

Answer (score 5):

I find the solution here, the simple solution is to delete the previous versions as explained below.

**To delete an application version**

- Open the Elastic Beanstalk console, and in the Regions list, select your AWS Region.
- In the navigation pane, choose Applications, and then choose your application's name from the list.

> Note
>
> If you have many applications, use the search bar to filter the
> application list.
>
> In the navigation pane, find your application's name and choose
> Application versions.

- Select one or more application versions that you want to delete.
- Choose Actions, then choose Delete.
- (Optional) To leave the application source bundle for these application versions in your Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) bucket, clear the box for Delete versions from Amazon S3.
- Choose Delete.

[image]

**Another solution**

Go to version settings and enable lifecycle policy the way it is shown below.

[image]
[image]

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-versions.html

Answer (score 4):

At the time of writing this answer, `eb labs cleanup-versions` does not work for me: it returned `No application versions to delete` even when I had application versions.

As a workaround, I used this one-liner inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23378928/400545) (change the **region** and **app name** accordingly):

> aws elasticbeanstalk describe-application-versions --output text --region=**us-west-2** --query 'ApplicationVersions[*].[ApplicationName,VersionLabel,DateCreated]' | grep **my-app-name** | while read app ver date; do echo "deleting version $app $ver $date" ; aws elasticbeanstalk delete-application-version --region=**us-west-2** --application-name $app --version-label $ver --delete-source-bundle; done

Answer (score 2):

Now, they have added an admin UI page to delete all application versions:

[Managing Application Versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-versions.html)

Answer (score 1):

There's no built in way to do that, but the following ruby script performs just that. Simply schedule it using cron.

```
clearnup.rb:

application_name="myApp"
active_versions_shell_output = `aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments --region=us-east-1 | grep git | awk '{gsub(/.*\:\ \"/,"",$0); print}'`
all_versions_shell_output = `aws elasticbeanstalk describe-applications --region=us-east-1 | grep git | awk '{gsub(/.*\ \"/,"",$0); print}'`
all_versions = all_versions_shell_output.split(/\n/).map{|x| x[0..57]}
active_versions = active_versions_shell_output.split(/\n/).map{|x| x[0..57]}

(all_versions - active_versions).each do |version_to_be_deleted|
    puts "deleting #{version_to_be_deleted}"
  `aws elasticbeanstalk delete-application-version --delete-source-bundle --application-name #{application_name} --version-label #{version_to_be_deleted}`
end
```